# Count number of appearance in a column in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I just want to ask if there is a way to count the appearance of data in a column like this on SSRS:

[image]

I would really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: im asking if i can do it without using query. just the resultset in the report.

Comment: I know literally nothing about SSRS, but according to this question and answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006471/ssrs-calculating-counts-across-row-and-column-groups, it sounds like you're better off just making a view to do it, then reporting based on that view. I know that isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it sounds like the standard practice. But I could be misunderstanding, since again I know nothing of this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Create another tablix and group it by the fruit column (make sure to add the group header).

Delete the detail row and the table header row so you are just left with the Group header.

If you want it all in one cell then use an expression something like =Field!Fruit.value & ": " & count(Field!Fruit.value)

You could always put the table inside the header or footer cell of the containing table

Answer (score 0):

1. First way - Add another table "tblGroups" after your detail
2. Second way - Add another row as the last row in the Fruits table outside of any grouping. Place "tblGroups" there.
3. Set a grouping condition "myFruitGroup" for tblGroups to =Fields!FruitID.Value
4. Set your text like `<Expression>=Fields!FruitName.Value+" : "+CSTR(COUNT(Fields!Fruit.ID,"myFruitGroup"))`